# How to perform zoom in/out ,rotation together in Android

Tags: android, multi-touch, image-rotation

I want to apply  drag,zoom in/out,rotate using multitouch to  two images .one 
       image is placed on the top of the other. after applying these action

[Create a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217188/how-create-a-new-image-by-mergingtwoimages)

from above  two images after
   changes made by applying actions.

I succeed in apply zoom/drag to top image ,created new image from that.

main problem is

> 1.How to apply action to two images, one image at a time ?
>
> 2.How to switch to another image from currently showing image
>            (which layout I should use)?
>
> 3.How user can have a facility to  rotate or zoom a image using multitouch ?

What I am missing, Sorry for the list -:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to keep the transformation done to Bitmap1 and apply it again to Bitmap2. for example you can use a Matrix calculated using touch events in order to apply it to the two Bitmaps.
2. I am not sure to uderstand what you want to do. What i understand is: you've got multiple imageview (that can be composed of 2 images placed on top of another) floating on the layout and you want to select one of them to resize / rotate it.
   In order to do that you can simply use the ontouch event of an imageView.
3. Rotate + zoom with multitouch is not easy in Android, lots of code have to be written in order to make it work nicely. I suggest you to use an existing library. I used this one and it worked like a charm:
   [https://github.com/lukehutch/android-multitouch-controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/)

You can see in the sample provided http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/source/browse/trunk/demo/MTPhotoSortr/src/org/metalev/multitouch/photosortr/PhotoSortrView.java that you can retreive at any time the new center, angle, and scale ratio of the updated images in `mImages(i).getCenterX()`, `mImages(i).getAngle()`, `mImages(i).getScaleX()`, ...
Using this values you can replicate the transformations (rotation, scaling, translation) on another Bitmap.

Comment: hi, I totally agree with you.rotation and zoominng worked like   a charm!!!!.it's perfect! .one Q ,if I am using this method.How to track transformation of images so that I can create third one from that .thanks

Comment: @Kariyachan I edited my answer describing how based on the sample provided with the library you can retrieve applied transformation to replicate them on another image.

Comment: I spent days on getting this right. Even tried the multitouch-controller that you linked to. Works fine on one phone and not on another. Verdict: Multi-touch on some Android phones is badly screwed up.

Comment: @Kariyachan Didn't work on HTC Desire, but the same code works fine on Samsung Galaxy 3. Here code means both, my simple home cooked one, as well as the android-multitouch-controller.

Comment: @HRJ mmmm I think problem is with something else because I implemented face cropper using this .It's working fine on HTC desire S.If Problem is with something else let's know thanks

Comment: @Kariyachan There might be a diff between Desire and Desire S. Can you try my app called "SkEye" on your Desire S? Enter manual mode by dragging the view and then try to rotate the view with two fingers. I will try your app as soon as I get back the Desire (later today)