# how to download android multi-touch controller library

Tags: android, multi-touch, android-library

I have to zoom in/zoom out and pan image using mutltitouch in android.I have followed motion event for two fingers but facing problem  when multiple fingers came into play with screen.I don't know how to get decision in case of movement of 4 or five fingers that whether user want  zoom or pan .i have found  library from

[How to perform zoom in/out ,rotation together in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256421/problem-with-performing-zoom-in-out-rotation-together)

I found a tutorial using this library  but didn't found any help to download this android-multitouch-controller library so i can use it as in tutorial it gives errors since library is not there.

Kindly guide me if any one ever use this library or is there any other way to decide mode in case of multitouch.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog on getting started with this library, if it still helps: http://paulbourke.blogspot.com/2011/10/writing-multitouch-applications-on.html